# I can't make line by point in Python script as in picture

Tags: python, revit-api

I can't make line by point in Python script as in picture

```
line1 = Autodesk Line ByStartPointEndPoint(t1, t2)
```

Please I need help.

How to code this in python script or in another language?
All code is all right but this not working ever.

Answer (score 2):

Welcome to the Revit API! Your question is impossible to answer with so little context. Please describe your situation. Do you have a working Revit add-in defining an external command implementing the [`IExternalCommand` interface](https://www.revitapidocs.com/2024/ad99887e-db50-bf8f-e4e6-2fb86082b5fb.htm) that is loading and executing successfully? If not, you should start by implementing that. The most efficient way to get to that point is to work through the [Revit API getting started material](https://thebuildingcoder.typepad.com/blog/about-the-author.html#2). Good luck, much success, and have fun!